# Summing over the reals

Tags: summation, real-numbers

Does $\sum_{k\in\Bbb{R}^{[a,b]}}f(k)$ converge for specific non-constant $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ ?

I know it's possible to sum over sets like $\Bbb{Z}$ or $\Bbb{P}$ but I haven't really seen anything about summing over the reals even if we restrict the summation interval and the function we're using. Does anyone know if this would even work?

Comment: It is possible to define the sum of a function $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$ on an arbitrary set $S$ as follows: $$ \sum_{x \in S} f(x) = \lim_{\substack{F \uparrow S \\ \text{$F$ finite}}} \sum_{x \in F} f(x) $$ This is a bit different from the ordinary summation for sequences, though. Indeed, $\sum_{x \in S} f(x)$ converges if and only if $\sum_{x \in S} |f(x)| $ converges. Consequently, conditional convergence, which critically hinges on the well-ordering structure of $\mathbb{N}$, does not occur for the sum $\sum_{x\in S}$.